# How to use boost weibull distribution library for random number generation?

Tags: c++, boost

I want to generate random numbers using weibull distribution in C++. Can anyone give me some hints ?

Thanks

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 5):

I think this can answer your question: [c++ References](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/weibull_distribution/)

```
// weibull_distribution
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
  const int nrolls=10000;  // number of experiments
  const int nstars=100;    // maximum number of stars to distribute

  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::weibull_distribution<double> distribution(2.0,4.0);

  int p[10]={};

  for (int i=0; i<nrolls; ++i) {
    double number = distribution(generator);
    if (number<10) ++p[int(number)];
  }

  std::cout << "weibull_distribution (2.0,4.0):" << std::endl;

  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << "-" << (i+1) << ": ";
    std::cout << std::string(p[i]*nstars/nrolls,'*') << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Pssible output:
weibull_distribution (2.0,4.0):

```
0-1: ******
1-2: ***************
2-3: *********************
3-4: ********************
4-5: ***************
5-6: ***********
6-7: *****
7-8: **
8-9: *
9-10:
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the Boost Library:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>        // For boost::mt19937
#include <boost/random/variate_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/random/weibull_distribution.hpp>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
    // Choose precision
    cout.precision(10);
    cout << endl;

    // To get random generated numbers:
    boost::mt19937 rng(12);
    double shape = 3.0;
    double scale = 0.5;
    boost::random::weibull_distribution<> myWeibull2(shape, scale);
    boost::random::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::random::weibull_distribution<> > rand_Weibull(rng, myWeibull2);

    cout << "Random numbers generated from a Weibull distribution:" << endl;
    double rn;
    for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        rn = rand_Weibull();
        cout << rn << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```